# how to redirect error action in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have to config common/main.php file in error handler but, not redirect error action. so please help me in this error.

main.php

```
'components' => [
.......
'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
.......
],
```

SiteController.php

```
 <?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
//use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use common\models\EmailTemplate;
use backend\components\BackendController;
use common\models\Users;

//use common\components\Helpers;
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends BackendController
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        //print "before action";exit;
        return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionError(){
        print "Here: Error Action";exit;
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(empty(Yii::$app->session['admin_user_id'])){
            return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
        }
        // Yii::$app->Helpers->getSettings('test');
        return $this->render('index');
    }


}
```

## Error Output:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Your request not found.' in F:\xampp\htdocs\school\backend\components\BackendController.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\backend\components\BackendController.php(25): backend\components\BackendController->checkpermission()
#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(107): backend\components\BackendController->init()
#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(81): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\Controller->__construct('site', Object(yii\web\Application), Array)
#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(366): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('backend\\control...', Array, Array)
#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(340): yii\di\Container->get('backend\\control...', Array)
#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(568): yii\BaseYii::createObject('backend\\control...', Array)
#8 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(521): yii\base\Module->createControllerByID('site')
#9 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(449): yii\base\Module->createController('site/error')
#10 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(80): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#11 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(101): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#12 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#13 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Your request not found.' in F:\xampp\htdocs\school\backend\components\BackendController.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\backend\components\BackendController.php(25): backend\components\BackendController->checkpermission()
#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(107): backend\components\BackendController->init()
#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(81): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\Controller->__construct('teacher', Object(yii\web\Application), Array)
#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(366): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('backend\\control...', Array, Array)
#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(340): yii\di\Container->get('backend\\control...', Array)
#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(568): yii\BaseYii::createObject('backend\\control...', Array)
#8 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(521): yii\base\Module->createControllerByID('teacher')
#9 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(449): yii\base\Module->createController('teacher/index')
#10 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('teacher/index', Array)
#11 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#12 F:\xampp\htdocs\school\backend\web\index.php(19): yii\base\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

any error found or throw error on show above output.
please help me

Comment: Please show your site controller . the `function action()` part

Comment: And the permission too (in controller)

Comment: scaisEdge: please show my full controller.

Comment: I have add an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration and in your actionError there arent' problem i used `echo` instead of `print` but is a minor.

For view the `actionError` work i have commented the  actions() this way

```
public function actions()
{
    /*return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];*/
}
```

Otherwise you always use the `yii\web\ErrorAction` class and not your function

By  the error message you show i think k the problem in not cause of you new error function but is related with some permission

Comment: i have to create permission module manually and throw error on "throw new NotFoundHttpException("Your request not found.");"

Comment: Then the your answer on `how redirect the error action in yii2` is  solved?

Comment: Sorry?  The question your show in your comment above how is related with the original question. I don't understand.